# How do I include a has_many relation when doing a Rails entity query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, has-many, relation

I'm using Rails 5.  I have a model with a has_many relation ...

```
class Book

    has_many :references, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
```

When querying for the entity,

```
book = Book.find(params[:id])
```

what do I need to add so that the has_many relation entities are also included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [includes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations) method for eager loading:

```
Book.includes(:references).find(params[:id])
```